# MAX(value) with TWO COLUMN

Tags: sql, hana

I have this value for exemple

```
 VAL1 VAL2
    04   ZZ
    06   TT
    05   XX
    03   XX
    04   ZZ
    09   TT
```

I want query that show me the max (last record) of each value of column val2

For exemple , for TT = 09 , XX = 03 , ZZ = 04 .

Can you please provide ? with HANA query if possible ?

Comment: Is it has something to do with `jquery`?

Comment: Would be useful to know which tag is the correct one for sql/sap/hana rather than [tag:jquery] (which is javascript)

Comment: What database engine are you using ? SQL server? oracle ?

Comment: SAP HANA database

Comment: The info of the tag "sap" says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG". SAP is a company. Just indicate the tag corresponding to the software, which is "HANA" in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know hana but SQL looks like this

```
select val2, max(val1) as maxVal
from myTable
group by val2
```

FROM SAP -
*"The generated SQL ANSI code is compliant and should work on most databases which are not yet supported by the application."*

The code ^^ I provided above is pretty much ANSI SQL, which should work in most SQL databases.

[More from SAP [ANSI SUPPORT]](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_SERVICE_CF/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/09940a1ed38c4ceb80770632997b286b.html?q=ansi%20hana&locale=en-US) - *"E051-02 -- GROUP BY clause  -- Full Support.....E091-03 -- MAX -- Full Support"*